# Screen scraping using a server to process the data

Tags: java, security, screen-scraping

The idea is the following.

1. The user sends credentials to the server (username,password).
2. Server tries to login to the website and parses useful data.  Some
       data remains to server in order to provide notifications if
       something changes in the next parse.
3. Server sends data to the user application.
4. User interacts with data and makes requests to server to receive
   data
5. loop between 3,4
6. logout

The problem is security and privacy. How to exchange this kind of information between server and the application securely? Also i don't like the idea of people sending me their credentials.

How to implement such a thing knowing that the site i am screen scraping does not provide an API to do this job?

Comment: connect to the web site and extract information from the web page using the dom tree of the HTML. Like HtmlUnit allows to do easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing their login details you could store the session cookie and reuse it until expires. Hopefully it would last step 5 but if not you could ask for their login details again.

Answer (score 0):

The only specific problem here is the screen-scraping, the other tasks are too vague to answer.

I can recommend [screen-scraper.com](http://screen-scraper.com/) (I am not affiliated in any way).